# Return value Of LINQ Query inside Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, repository, asp.net-core-webapi

I Create Method inside InterFace like This
 `List<T> OngoingEvent();`

and I implemented the Method Inside Repository

```
public List<T> OngoingEvent()
{
    var output2 = DbContext.ParticipantsTable.Join(DbContext.EventTable, e => e.EventTableID, d => d.ID,
         (tbl1, tbl2) => new
         {
             Table1 = tbl1,
             Table2 = tbl2
         }).Join(DbContext.VolunteerTable, ee => ee.Table1.VolunteerTableID, dd => dd.ID,
         (tbl1, tbl2) => new
         {
             ID = tbl1.Table1.ID,
             IsAccepted = tbl1.Table1.IsAccepted,
             IsAttend = tbl1.Table1.IsAttend,
             EventName = tbl1.Table2.EventName,
             EventEndDate = tbl1.Table2.EventEndDate,
             VolunteerName = tbl2.VolunteerName
         }).ToList();

    return output2;

}
```

but I get Error for the return value

Severity Code Description Project File  Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int Id, bool Accepted, bool Attend, string EventName, string EventEndDate, string VolunteerName>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

I Try To change
 `List<T> OngoingEvent();`
to
IEnumerable OngoingEvent();`

and
IQueryable OngoingEvent();`
but Not working

and I try to use Method like this
IQueryable OngoingEvent(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
but o don't know how i can deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the return type of a list of `output2` which is an anonymous object by virtue of using:

```
new
{
    DynamicProp1Name = value1,
    DynamicProp2Name = value2,
    ... etc ...
}
```

cannot be converted to a list of type `T`.

You could solve your problem quickly by changing the signature to either:

```
public List<object> OngoingEvent();
```

or

```
public List<dynamic> OngoingEvent();
```

However, I would go for defining a class that represents the return type:

```
public class OngoingEventResult
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }
    public bool IsAttend { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventEndDate { get; set; }
    public string VolunteerName { get; set; }
}
```

and then using this as the return type:

```
public List<OngoingEventResult> OngoingEvent()
{
    ...
    (tbl1, tb2) => new OngoingEventResult()
    {
        ID = tbl1.Table1.ID,
        IsAccepted = tbl1.Table1.IsAccepted,
        IsAttend = tbl1.Table1.IsAttend,
        EventName = tbl1.Table2.EventName,
        EventEndDate = tbl1.Table2.EventEndDate,
        VolunteerName = tbl2.VolunteerName    
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neil W To help me 
I try to Change in the inerface 
 List<object> OngoingEvent();
and i change in repository 
 List<ParticipantsTable>  OngoingEvent()
        {..
return output2;
} buu still get Error

Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int ID, bool IsAccepted, bool IsAttend, string EventName, string EventEndDate, string VolunteerName>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'

Comment: If you're still using the `anonymous type` but want to return a list of `object`, instead of creating an `OngoingEventResult`, then you'll need to finish with `.ToList<object>()`.

Comment: However, I still strongly recommend using a defined class such as `OngoingEventResult` instead of using `anonymous` and `object` or `dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil  it's works 
when i use ToList<object>()

i was defined  three class

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil  it's works 
when i use ToList<object>()

i was create  three  model classes
ParticipantsTable
EventTable
VolunteerTable

and the query uses This three tables 

and i have three folder 
models (to define three tables above )
interface (List<object> OngoingEvent();)
repository (the query above )

do i on the right track